# Assign + or - sign to the first n natural numbers to get the given value

Tags: algorithm, numbers

Given the first 9 natural numbers we have to assign + or - sign to each number such that the sum of the resulting sequence is equal to the required number.

For example, we are given the first 9 natural numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and have to get the value 1.

The output can be {1,-2,3,4,-5,-6,7,8,-9} or any one of the other possibilities.

if the value is -5, then the output can be {-1,-2,-3,4,-5,-6,7,-8,9}.

We know that the sum will always be odd.

I am unable to come up with an algorithm that could solve this problem.

My idea was to use a greedy approach.(we can assume the sequence is sorted)

1. Start from the largest value (right side of the sequence).
2. Sum the numbers till current index.
3. Check if the sum of sequence is lower than absolute value of the target number.
4. If yes, then assign the + to the number at the current index otherwise a -.
5. Repeat till we reach the first number.

Based on my algorithm the output for,

1 is {1 -2 3 4 -5 6 -7 8 -9}

15 is {1 2 -3 4 -5 6 7 -8 9}. Giving me the sum of the sequence as 13 (completely wrong).

Here is my code,

```
 public static int[] sequenceOfSigns(int[] num, int sum) {

    int n = num[num.length - 1];
    int upperBound = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;

    if (sum % 2 == 0 || sum < -upperBound || sum > upperBound)
        return null;

    int tempSum = 0;

    for (int i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tempSum += num[i];

        boolean flag;

        if (i != 0)
            flag = tempSum >= Math.abs(sum);
        else
            flag = tempSum > Math.abs(sum);

        if (flag) {
            num[i] = -num[i];
            tempSum += num[i] * 2;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Any ideas on how to modify the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally can we extend the problem to n natural numbers? or is it an NP-problem?

**EDIT**

I have solved this problem another way.

Here is the solution with proof that was inspired by my brother's suggestion on how to solve the problem. His suggestion is superbly elegant.

**My Proof**
Given a sequence of natural numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and an odd target sum of x; we are to modify the sign(+/-) of the numbers in the sequence such that the sum of the elements equals the target number.

Let A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

x is the target number (odd).

Let us consider a set S which contains all the elements of A that should be made negative.

Then we have the relation,

Sum of all elements in A - (2 * Sum of all elements in S) = |x|
[This is the key idea suggested by my brother]

Rearranging the equation we get,

Sum of all elements in S = (Sum of all elements in A - |x|)/2 .... (1)

Now, we select the largest value in A which is lesser than or equal to the sum in (1).

We subtract this from the sum in (1).

We perform this operation, iteratively, till the sum in (1) becomes 0.

A point to note is that each value from A can only be selected once.

This is our greedy algorithm.

This choice of largest element in A which is lesser than or equal to the sum at each step is a safe greedy choice. Since, the selected values will form the set of numbers which should be negative the sum of the selected values and the sum in (1) should be same.

Now, if we select a value greater than the sum in (1) the difference would be a negative value and that is a contradiction. Hence, we cannot select a greater value.

If we arbitrarily choose any value that is lesser than or equal to the sum in (1), the difference is positive or 0. We can easily replace the selected value with the largest value that satisfies the conditions and the constraints are still obeyed. So, our choice is a safe choice.

The values selected in the previous step form the set S.

and our required sequence is the ordered set formed from the set,

(A - S) U -(elements in S)

If x is negative we simply flip the signs in the ordered set obtained above. Since, the solutions for x and -x are symmetric.

This concludes our proof and solution for the greedy algorithm

**CODE**

```
public static int[] sequenceOfSigns(int[] num, int sum) {

    int n = num[num.length - 1];
    int upperBound = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;

    if (sum % 2 == 0 || sum < -upperBound || sum > upperBound)
        return null;

    int negativeSeqSum = (upperBound - Math.abs(sum)) / 2;

    for (int i = num.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        if (num[i] <= negativeSeqSum) {
            negativeSeqSum -= num[i];
            num[i] = -num[i];
        }
        if (negativeSeqSum == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (sum == -Math.abs(sum))
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
            num[i] = -num[i];

    return num;
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by using the following intuition:

- Any number could get a + or - sign.
- Lets say the last number is 'n' and you could mark it positive or negative

  - If you mark it positive:
    Then remaining sum is S - n and you have to solve the problem for n-1 numbers and target sum = S - n
  - If you mark it negative:
    Then remaining sum is S + n and you have to solve the problem for n-1 numbers and target sum = S + n

Therefore you could write the following recursion:

```
isPossible(N, S) = isPossible(N-1, S-N) || isPossible(N-1, S+N)
```

You could memoize the solution at each combination of (N, S) and store the result in a map of

```
Pair ( N, S) => Boolean
```

Now from the map you could go through the pairs which have true values i.e. ( for the pair's 'N' numbers it is possible to get sum equal to the pair's S) and get the appropriate signs like below example :

The map for the case N = 9 and S = -5 looks like:

```
{(1, -31)=false, (2, -33)=false, (6, -29)=false, (2, -37)=false, (5, -35)=false, (4, -4)=true, (2, -41)=false, (3, -10)=false, (3, -14)=false, (4, -16)=false, (3, -18)=false, (3, -22)=false, (3, -26)=false, (7, -22)=true, (4, -28)=false, (3, -30)=false, (1, -1)=true, (3, -34)=false, (2, -3)=true, (1, -5)=false, (2, -7)=false, (1, -9)=false, (4, -40)=false, (1, -49)=false, (2, -11)=false, (1, -13)=false, (5, -9)=true, (9, -5)=true, (1, -45)=false, (2, -15)=false, (1, -17)=false, (1, -41)=false, (2, -19)=false, (6, -15)=true, (1, -21)=false, (1, -37)=false, (2, -23)=false, (1, -25)=false, (5, -21)=false, (1, -33)=false, (2, -27)=false, (1, -29)=false, (2, -31)=false, (3, 0)=true, (2, -35)=false, (2, -39)=false, (3, -8)=false, (3, -12)=false, (2, -47)=false, (4, -14)=false, (4, -18)=false, (8, -14)=true, (3, -20)=false, (3, -24)=false, (4, -26)=false, (4, -30)=false, (3, -32)=false, (1, -3)=false, (3, -36)=false, (2, -5)=false, (1, -7)=false, (2, -9)=false, (1, -11)=false, (3, -44)=false, (2, -13)=false, (1, -15)=false, (1, -43)=false, (2, -17)=false, (1, -19)=false, (1, -39)=false, (2, -21)=false, (1, -23)=false, (1, -35)=false, (2, -25)=false, (1, -27)=false, (5, -23)=false, (2, -29)=false}
```

Start with the key = Pair(9, -5) is it there in the map with a value of "true"?

Yes it is there, now look for two possibilities : Pair(8, -5-9) or Pair(8, -5+9)
It turns out that Pair(8, -14) exists, so you need to add +9 to the list because you need to look for S - n i.e. you are subtracting n from the remaining S you are looking for. Then update S =  S- n = -5 - 9 = -14.

Now look for two possiblities : Pair(7, -14-8) or Pair(7, -14+8). It turns out that Pair(7, -22) exists, so you need to add +8 to the list because you need to look for S - n which means you subtracted n = 8 from the remaining S you are looking for. Then update S = S - n = -14 - 8 = -22

....
....

The final result will be `[-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]`

Code is - ( you can play with the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/CrispColossalLava) by modifying N, S)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Main {
    private static Map<Pair, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int N = 9;
        int S = -5;
        Integer[] result = sequenceOfSigns(N, S);
        System.out.println(("Input = " + N + ", " + S + " : ") + ( result == null ? "Not possible" : Arrays.toString(result)));
        S = 15;
        result = sequenceOfSigns(N, S);
        System.out.println(("Input = " + N + ", " + S + " : ") + ( result == null ? "Not possible" : Arrays.toString(result)));
        S = 45;
        result = sequenceOfSigns(N, S);
        System.out.println(("Input = " + N + ", " + S + " : ") + ( result == null ? "Not possible" : Arrays.toString(result)));
        S = -45;
        result = sequenceOfSigns(N, S);
        System.out.println(("Input = " + N + ", " + S + " : ") + ( result == null ? "Not possible" : Arrays.toString(result)));
        S = 4;
        result = sequenceOfSigns(N, S);
        System.out.println(("Input = " + N + ", " + S + " : ") + ( result == null ? "Not possible" : Arrays.toString(result)));     
        
    }
    
    public static Integer[] sequenceOfSigns(int N, int sum) {
        boolean isPossible = helper(N, sum);
        if ( isPossible ) {
            int s = sum;
            
            List<Integer> res_list = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( int n = N; n >= 1; n-- ) {
                Pair p = new Pair(n, s);
                if ( n == 1 ) {
                    res_list.add(s);
                } else if ( map.containsKey(p) && map.get(p) ) {
                    Pair p1 = new Pair(n-1, s+n);
                    Pair p2 = new Pair(n-1, s-n);
                    if (map.containsKey(p1)) {
                        res_list.add(-n);
                        s = s + n;
                    } else if ( map.containsKey(p2)) {
                        res_list.add(n);
                        s = s - n;
                    }
                }
            }
            Collections.reverse(res_list);
            if ( !res_list.isEmpty() ) return res_list.toArray(new Integer[] {});
        }
        return null;
    }
    

    private static boolean helper(int N, int S) {
        
        if ( N == 0 ) return S == 0;
        Pair p  = new Pair(N, S);
        if ( map.containsKey(p) ) {
            return map.get(p);
        }
        boolean val = helper(N-1, S - N) || helper(N-1, S + N);
        map.put(p,  val);
        return val;
    }
    
    static class Pair {
        int N, S;
        public Pair(int N, int S) {
            this.N = N;
            this.S = S;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if ( obj instanceof Pair ) {
                Pair other = (Pair)obj;
                return other.N == N && other.S == S;
            }
            return false;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31*31*N + 31*S;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + N + ", " + S + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input = 9, -5 : [-1, -2, 3, -4, -5, -6, -7, 8, 9]
Input = 9, 15 : [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Input = 9, 45 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Input = 9, -45 : [-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
Input = 9, 4 : Not possible
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^9 = 512 possibilities. Why not brute force?

```js
var hash = {0: [[]]};

for (let i=1; i<=9; i++){
  let new_hash = {};
  for (let _sum in hash){
    let sum = Number(_sum);
    let new_sum = sum + i;
    if (new_sum in new_hash)
      new_hash[new_sum] = new_hash[new_sum].concat(hash[sum].map(x => x.concat(i)));
    else
      new_hash[new_sum] = hash[sum].map(x => x.concat(i));
    new_sum = sum - i;
    if (new_sum in new_hash)
      new_hash[new_sum] = new_hash[new_sum].concat(hash[sum].map(x => x.concat(-i)));
    else
      new_hash[new_sum] = hash[sum].map(x => x.concat(-i));
  }
  hash = new_hash;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(hash[1]));
console.log('');
console.log(JSON.stringify(hash[15]));
```